# Use fgetcsv() without using fopen(), popen(), or fsockopen()?

Tags: php, curl, csv

I would like to use `fgetcsv()` function but in the PHP document it say I have to use  `fopen()`, `popen()`, or `fsockopen()`

I would like `fgetcsv()` to load from the string instead of file.

How can that be done?

For example:

```
//Get data from Curl 
$curlData = "aaaa,111111,22222,33333
             bbbbb,xxxx,dddddd,eeee
            "

while($row = fgetcsv($curlData,"1000",",")) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [str_getcsv()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) then

Comment: This can only be used if you are using >= PHP 5.3. How about the old versions?

Comment: @Louie Miranda - As PHP versions prior to 5.3 have not been supported since 17th March 2011 (9 months before this question was originally asked), you really should be upgrading to a supported version of PHP... if you're stuck with earlier versions because of hosting, ask a specific question identifying the version that you're using - don't just arbitrarily downvote correct answers just because they don't work in unsupported versions of PHP

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to perform this task.